# Will Wubi Ubuntu installer conflict with my current Grub Menu?

Tags: wubi

I have a desktop where I dual-boot Windows XP and Lubuntu. Given that Wubi makes use of Windows Boot Menu, If I install Ubuntu 12.04 from Wubi installer on Windows, will it be present on Grub Menu? Will there be any conflict between Wubi and Grub Menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't conflict but Wubi won't show up in Grub either. Wubi adds itself to the Win XP boot menu, so to boot Wubi the process would be:

1. Grub: Lubuntu or WinXP?
2. Choose WinXP
3. WinXP boot menu: WinXP or Wubi?
4. Choose Wubi
   (you may then get a Wubi grub menu asking you to choose a kernel, recovery mode, etc.)

Comment: No, I think you're right but IiRC newer Wubi versions skip the menu by default.

Comment: Grub on a Wubi install bypasses Windows entries, not linux entries. So the Wubi grub menu will show, and it will have the Wubi install and Lubuntu (but no entry for windows).